gorm inserting unsupported data
I am trying to insert a struct Named Teacher into sqlite database using gorm, when i call the create function i get the error saying:
INSERT INTO `teachers` (`name`,`department`,`password`) VALUES  RETURNING `id`
panic: unsupported data

this is my teacher struct:
type Teacher struct {
    Id         int    `json:"id" db:"id" gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name       string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Department string `json:"department" db:"department"`
    Password   string `json:"-" db:"password"`
}

this is how i am inserting:
data := Teacher{
        Id:         0,
        Name:       "JohnDoe",
        Department: "ComputerScience",
        Password:   "12312312312321",
    }
DB.Create(&data)

EDIT:
Some more code for understanding:
main.go:
t := models.Teacher{
        Id:         0,
        Name:       "JohnDoe",
        Department: "ComputerScience",
        Password:   "12312312312321",
    }
    t.CreateTeacher()

teacher.go:
type Teacher struct {
    Id         int    `json:"id" db:"id" gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name       string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Department string `json:"department" db:"department"`
    Password   string `json:"-" db:"password"`
}

func (teacher Teacher) CreateTeacher() error {
    fmt.Println(teacher)
    err := database.Insert(teacher)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return nil
}


database.go:
func ConnectDatabase() error {
    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("./cisl-database.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func Insert(data interface{}) error {
    fmt.Print(data)
    err := ConnectDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    DB.AutoMigrate(&data)
    
    if err := DB.Create(&data).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}


I hope it will be a huge help for answering, if you put your whole code here in the question.

i added some more code

// ...
func Insert(data interface{}) error {
// ...

cuz you pass the interface{} type to the gorm, it can't process it. you need to change to
func Insert(data Teacher) error {

btw, imo, i don't think the code is best practice :)
maybe you can consider just calling the db instance to Create(&data) or other actions like Transaction and so on.

This works however i was trying to make the insert function as a global function so i can i insert any struct using it. but it looks like i will have to stick to simple sql rather then gorm. Thanks!
